# Как проверить, все ли элементы одинаковы в списке?

Tags: python

```
n = int(input())
sp = []
for _ in range(n):
  sp.append(int(input()))
```

Как проверить, все ли числа одинаковые в этом списке?

Comment: А собственных идей совсем никаких?

Comment: @Эникейщик думал как то создать второй список и с помощью цикла for заносить во второй список и потом предыдущий с текущим сравнивать элементом при добавлении в него, но это слишком переусложнено

Comment: Да, это слишком переусложнено. Достаточно сравнивать каждый элемент списка с первым элементом (или любым другим).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

например так:

способ 1:

```
if len(set(sp)) == 1:
    print("ОДИНАКОВЫЕ!!!")
```

способ 2:

```
if [i for i in sp if i != sp[0]] == []:
    print("ОДИНАКОВЫЕ!!!")
```

способ 3 (скорее всего самый быстрый):

```
if sp.count(sp[0]) == len(sp):
    print("ОДИНАКОВЫЕ!!!")
```

Answer (score 10):

Можно воспользоваться встроенной функцией [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
res = all(x == sp[0] for x in sp)
```

Comment: Вот это оптимальный вариант, т.к. при отрицательном ответе он не будет перебирать остаток списка.

Answer (score 5):

Добавлю вариант для любого `iterable`. Мне повезло обойтись без обработки исключений для пустой коллекции. Варианты с [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) самые быстрые, так как останавливаются на первом неравенстве:

```
def the_same(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    first = next(it, None)
    return all(v == first for v in it)


print(the_same(int(input()) for _ in range(int(input()))))
```

Comment: `set` работает с любым итерируемым объектом

Comment: Согласен. Поправьте у себя `== 1` на `<= 1`. Будет пустой список правильно работать.

Comment: я не Zhihar, я Danis ;D

Comment: Упс. Обознался. Прошу прощения.

Comment: А теперь пример где всё не работает. Мой любимый: `[math.nan, math.nan]`.

Comment: этот пример и не должен работать по определению `nan`, т.к. `nan` не равен самому себе - `(math.nan == math.nan) == False`

Comment: Тем он и прекрасен.

Comment: с этим не поспоришь)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a'])
u, indices, count = np.unique(a, return_index=True, return_counts=True)
print(u)
# array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='<U1')
print(count)
# array([2, 2, 1], dtype=int64)
print(count[count > 1])  # где значения больше 1 == дубликат
# array([2, 2], dtype=int64)
print(indices)
# array([0, 1, 3])
print(a[indices])
# array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='<U1')
print(len(a) - len(u))
# 2
print(np.sum(count - 1))
# 2
```